# Send post variable from aspx to php and get result

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i try to send with ajax a post variable from a aspx site to a php site, but i don´t get a answer.

ASPX site:

```
$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url:"www.mySite.com/sqlExecute.php",
data: {'d':'empty'},
dataType: "text",
success: function(data) {
  alert (data);
}
});
```

sqlExecute.php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

If i add the error function:

```
error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert("jqXHR: "+jqXHR.responsetext+" textStatus: "+textStatus+" errorThrown: "+ errorThrown );}
```

});

i get:

```
jqXHR: undefined textStatus: error errorThrown:
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check your error console. Unless the php site is set up to do CORS, you're limited by the same origin policy.

Comment: Would adding `http://` in `url:"www.mySite.com/sqlExecute.php",` make a difference? As in `url:"http://www.mySite.com/sqlExecute.php",` -- you could also try adding `contentType: "application/json",` and using `alert("Here's lots of data, just a string: " + data);`

Answer (score 0):

When you write ajax calls its always good to configure the error handler too.

If this can, specify the protocol. Otherwise it will be treated as a relative url.

You can see the call in a debug tool like firebug or fiddler.

```
$.ajax ({
 type: "POST",
 url:"http://www.mySite.com/sqlExecute.php",
 data: {'d':'empty'},
 dataType: "text",
 success: function(data) {
  alert (data);
 }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer, the main problem was the header on the php site:

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
     data: {'d':'empty'},
    url : 'http://mysite.de/sqlExecute.php',
    success : function(sqlArray) {
    console.log(sqlArray.a);
    }});

<?php
```

php site:

```
<?php 
$json = json_encode(array("a" =>  "Hello World"));
header("Content-Type: application/json");
print $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $json . ")";
?>
```